# Как побороть выравнивание по родительскому div?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, ребят подскажите, как решить одну проблемку.

Есть родительский div(overflow: hidden) у которого childs с абсолютным позиционированием, длинна сhild неизвестна и выставляется по размеру текста. У границ родительского div текст начинает по ним выравниваться. Как сделать так, чтобы он просто выходил за границу и сохранял свою длину?

Пример - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HStXC/)

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="child1">One two three</div>
    <div id="child2">One two three</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#main {
    position:relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#child1, #child2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#child1 {
    top: 10px;
    left: 60px;
}
#child2 {
    top: 70px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть один способ без применения **javascript**

```
#main {
    overflow: visible;
}

#child1, #child2 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

К сожалению, для родительского блока придется поставить **overflow: visible**. Без этого никак.

**[Ваш исправленный пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/HStXC/2/)**

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
Нужен именно hidden, чтобы элементы не были видны за пределами родительского div. Буду делать с помошью js